# Approach to react component switching between subcomponents with form

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

I am currently doing my first FE project I am supposed to create completely by myself.

I have a component which is supposed to hold 3 subcomponents, each of them is supposed to show a form.

Currently I have chosen approach I was pretty happy with, but then I started to think about testing, and I realised I am basicly not able to create a test for parent component, without a dependence on child components. The parent component is something like this:

```
return (
<div className="personal-data-step-wrapper">
  {currentForm === 0 && <UserDataForm handleChangeForm={handleChangeForm}
                                      setValues={setUserDataFormValues}
                                      defaultValues={userDataFormValues}/>}
  {currentForm === 1 && <CertificateDataForm handleChangeForm={handleChangeForm}
                                             setValues={setCertificateDataFormValues}
                                             defaultValues={certificateDataFormValues}/>}
  {currentForm === 2 && <QSCDDeviceDataForm onStepFinish={onFinish}
                                            handleChangeForm={handleChangeForm}
                                            setValues={setQSCDeviceDataFormValues}
                                            defaultValues={qSCDDeviceDataFormValues}/>}
</div>
)
```

And then in a child component:

```
const onFinish = () => {
setValues({
  documentType: form.getFieldValue("documentType"),
  documentIssueDate: form.getFieldValue("documentIssueDate"),
  documentFullName: form.getFieldValue("documentFullName"),
  documentNumber: form.getFieldValue("documentNumber"),
  documentAddress: form.getFieldValue("documentAddress")
})
handleChangeForm(1)
}
```

You can see that changing between forms is done in child components, after it's successful submission or when switching to previous form. After last form is submitted, parent component gathers data of all child forms into an single object and call a repository interface function with it.

When I try to create a test which should test switching between components, I am forced to find a button of rendered child component and I feel like this is a wrong approach.

So my question would be: How am I supposed to handle such a task? Is my approach correct, or is it fundamentaly wrong?

Thank you for all suggestions and replies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty obvious that you should invoke your `handleChangeForm()` from within your parent component, like so:

a) if it's a class component

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.currentForm !== prevState.currentForm)
        this.handleChangeForm(this.state.currentForm);
}
```

b) if it's a functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleChangeForm(currentForm);
}, [currentForm]);
```

I've supposed that your `changeForm` is a state value, but anyhow you get the idea...

**edit**

If you want to exclude the form-changing logic from the children, you could move the "next" button to the parent. This way, you'd just ask the relevant child if the form inputs are valid, and if the child confirms - go ahead and change the form, from within the parent.

What you've asked for is to test this logic w/o including the children. And it'd be totally possible, you would just mock the "confirmation" from the children (eg. simple true/false).

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I got the idea, but I am not sure how to invoke the component change in parent component, when buttons used for changing forms are contained in a child components. handleChangeForm method is a method which calls setCurrentForm (state value setter) while making sure that the value is in a specific range. Currently my approach just sends handleChangeForm setter as a prop to a child component, and the child component calls handleChangeForm when submit button is clicked.

Comment: If both the method and the state value are located in your parent component, I don't see the problem here...

Comment: I want the parent component to be as child independent as possible (maybe that is a wrong approach). So when I am creating a test, I want to switch between all three possible currrentForm states without even knowing that the childs were rendered, which now isnt possible cozI need to locate a continue button which is a part of child component. My first idea was to put the control buttons onto parent form, but this way I am not able to invoke child form validations which would prevent me to proceed to next form if data were invalid. So how do you think I should call handleChangeForm in my test?

Comment: Thank you, this really seems like an idea I would be happy with. I was thinking about it before, but how do I ask a children for confirmation? I would somehow need to call a form.submit function which would then propagate result status of submition into parent component. I only came with a solution where I would pass a state boolean "submit" into a child and then in the child I would use useEffect with condition on submit value, which would in case of true value call form.submit, and then I would need to pass state value setter which would send the result into parent. Do you know better way?

Comment: If you need further assistance, post your validation logic (implementation)

Comment: @omastik Anyways, you could pass a "submit" action down to your child and then its result (valid or not) back up to your parent (by props of course).